# What are valid values of `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority()` when using STM32 and FreeRTOS?

Tags: c, stm32, freertos

After a rather difficult process of learning some things about interrupt priority, I am still a bit stuck trying to understand what values I am allowed to call for `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority()` on the `SysTick_IRQn` (which is the ISR calling the FreeRTOS scheduler every 1 ms).

## TLDR;

Part of me thinks that anything between `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15 ,0U)` (lowest priority possible) and `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 10 ,0U)` (a bit higher) are allowed, and part of me thinks that anything between `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15 ,0U)` (lowest priority possible) and `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 5 ,0U)` (quite a bit higher) is allowed. This is assuming that `configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY` in FreeRTOSConfig.h is set to 5. The confusion lies in the fact that in FreeRTOS, higher numbers are higher priority, but in STM32, higher numbers are *lower* priority, and the documentation is pretty challenging to understand.

---

## Details:

To prove I've made a valiant effort, and to help you help me fill in the blanks, here's my current understanding. I'm going to write a description of what I know to be true in such a way that it looks like *I* am teaching *you*, even though I'm seeking the answer to my above question, as well as  **correction**, **confirmation**, or **additional insight** as you see fit.

Though this probably applies to many of the STM32 microcontrollers or families, let's discuss it in terms of the [STM32F207ZG](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f207zg.html) in particular.

Note: [STM32CubeF2 download is here](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32cubef2.html#getsoftware-scroll).

### My understanding:

If you look at a standard **FreeRTOSConfig.h** file (ex: STM32Cube_FW_F2_V1.7.0/Projects/STM322xG_EVAL/Applications/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS_ThreadCreation/Inc/FreeRTOSConfig.h) you'll see the following:

```
/* Cortex-M specific definitions. */
#ifdef __NVIC_PRIO_BITS
    /* __BVIC_PRIO_BITS will be specified when CMSIS is being used. */
    #define configPRIO_BITS             __NVIC_PRIO_BITS
#else
    #define configPRIO_BITS             4        /* 15 priority levels */
#endif

/* The lowest interrupt priority that can be used in a call to a "set priority"
function. */
#define configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY         0xf

/* The highest interrupt priority that can be used by any interrupt service
routine that makes calls to interrupt safe FreeRTOS API functions.  DO NOT CALL
INTERRUPT SAFE FREERTOS API FUNCTIONS FROM ANY INTERRUPT THAT HAS A HIGHER
PRIORITY THAN THIS! (higher priorities are lower numeric values. */
#define configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY    5

/* Interrupt priorities used by the kernel port layer itself.  These are generic
to all Cortex-M ports, and do not rely on any particular library functions. */
#define configKERNEL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY         ( configLIBRARY_LOWEST_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS) )
/* !!!! configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY must not be set to zero !!!!
See http://www.FreeRTOS.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html. */
#define configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY    ( configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS) )
```

`__NVIC_PRIO_BITS` is defined in *STM32Cube_FW_F2_V1.7.0/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F2xx/Include/stm32f217xx.h* as `4U` since "STM32F2XX uses 4 Bits for the Priority Levels".

First off, this is interesting because it means that only 4 of the available 8 priority bits are actually used! The STM32 HAL library call `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority()` has a header that looks as follows, and seems to indicate you have 8 bits to set (`PreemptPriority` from 0 to 15 and `SubPriority` from 0 to 15), but really you don't--you only have 4 bits to set.

```
/**
  * @brief  Sets the priority of an interrupt.
  * @param  IRQn: External interrupt number.
  *         This parameter can be an enumerator of IRQn_Type enumeration
  *         (For the complete STM32 Devices IRQ Channels list, please refer to the appropriate CMSIS device file (stm32f2xxxx.h))
  * @param  PreemptPriority: The preemption priority for the IRQn channel.
  *         This parameter can be a value between 0 and 15
  *         A lower priority value indicates a higher priority 
  * @param  SubPriority: the subpriority level for the IRQ channel.
  *         This parameter can be a value between 0 and 15
  *         A lower priority value indicates a higher priority.          
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t PreemptPriority, uint32_t SubPriority)
{
```

So, you only have 4 bits to set, but it turns out you can decide how many are `PreemptPriority` bits and how many are `SubPriority` bits, as follows:

`HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping()` from [UM1940](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/56/32/53/cb/69/86/49/0e/DM00223149.pdf/files/DM00223149.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00223149.pdf), 9.2.4, p124/1371.
[image]

[FreeRTOS says in their documentation](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html):

> If you are using an STM32 with the STM32 driver library then ensure all the priority bits are assigned to be preempt priority bits by calling NVIC_PriorityGroupConfig( NVIC_PriorityGroup_4 ); before the RTOS is started.

So, one of the very first things you should do in your code (at least before starting the FreeRTOS scheduler via `osKernelStart()` or `vTaskStartScheduler()` is:

```
/* Set Interrupt Group Priority */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(NVIC_PRIORITYGROUP_4);
```

This configures all 4 of your priority bits to be `PreemptPriority` bits and none to be `SubPriority` bits. This means any calls to the `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t PreemptPriority, uint32_t SubPriority)` function will now *always use 0 as the right-most parameter.*

You should then essentially call (note: this is called via `HAL_InitTick()`:

```
/*Configure the SysTick IRQ priority */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15 ,0U);
```

where `15` is the SysTick tick priority. Since we have all 4 bits available, this gives us a priority range of 0 to 15, with 15 being the *lowest* interrupt priority and 0 being the *highest* priority.

Well, why are we setting SysTick to the *lowest* priority? Answer: because this is a good practice for the FreeRTOS scheduler, which the SysTick interrupt calls. As a matter of fact, giving it too high a priority will break FreeRTOS, according to their own documentation. Let's try to figure that out.

We know that our interrupt options now are 0 to 15 for the `PreemptPriority` setting, but it's even narrower than that: we can only set our PreemptPriority for the SysTick interrupt to be **10 to 15** (I think--I need some help here). Why 10 to 15? Well, the [FreeRTOS documentation](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html) (albeit this is super confusing) even expressly states:

> FreeRTOS functions that end in "FromISR" are interrupt safe, but even these functions cannot be called from interrupts that have a logical priority above [ie: numerically lower] the priority defined by configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY (configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY is defined in the FreeRTOSConfig.h header file). Therefore, any interrupt service routine that uses an RTOS API function must have its priority manually set to a value that is numerically equal to or greater than the configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY setting. This ensures the interrupt's logical priority is equal to or less than the configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY setting.

Now, refer back to **FreeRTOSConfig.h** at the top of this page. We know `__NVIC_PRIO_BITS` is 4 and we see that:

`configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY` is `(configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY << (8 - configPRIO_BITS))`, which means it is `5 << (8 - 4) = decimal 80 = 0b01010000`.

The FreeRTOS documentation offers some valuable insight into why the left-shift (see the section titled "Cortex-M Internal Priority Representation"), but I can't discern beyond that.

So now making some educated guesses and knowing our priority options are 0 to 15 with 0 being highest and 15 being lowest, and knowing that configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY is 5, we maybe are allowed to use 15 - 5 = 10 as highest priority and 15 as lowest, or maybe 5 to 15 is ok but 0 to 4 is off-limits? I don't know...I'm confused...

Comment: I would say - if you do not understand how the priority system works, better do not touch it in such a complex environment as RTOS.  First learn how it works in the bare metal environment, consider why you want to change it and when you become the NVIC master tune the RTOS. I would suggest to use the CMSIS functions instead

Comment: Gabriel, thx for this question ! This really helped me in understanding more on this topic :). Quite a challenging road so far..!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly do not confuse FreeRTOS task priorities with NVIC priorities. They are entirely different.

In the above example you can use interrupt priorities of 5 to 15 for your interrupts if they make FreeRTOS API calls. If they do not make FreeRTOS API calls then you can use interrupts of any priority from 0 to 15.

Don't worry about the shifting as it is all handled for you, but the reason is the top 4 bits of the priority registers are used (note some processors use a different number of priority bits).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Ok, so `configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY` is describing an **NVIC priority then, correct**--even though it's inside FreeRTOSConfig.h? And a FreeRTOS (task) priority would be what you pass in when you call `xTaskCreate(taskFunction, "Task Name", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE * 5, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1, NULL)`, for instance, where the FreeRTOS task priority in this example is 1 higher than the idle task.

Comment: So, to confirm: `configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY` is a limit on NVIC priorities (which are passed to `HAL_NVIC_SetPriority()`) and the FreeRTOS priorities are used in `xTaskCreate()`, `uxTaskPriorityGet()`, `vTaskPrioritySet()`, etc, correct? This is the distinction you refer to when you say not to confuse the two?

Comment: Yes. The MAX SYSCALL PRIORITY is the maximum NVIC priority of an interrupt that can make call into the system (API). The reason for this is that the RTOS uses higher priority interrupts which should not be interrupted by calls into the RTOS as they would corrupt the RTOS data. As you say Task Priorities are used by xTaskCreate, where 0 is lowest priority task.